# How to filter an SSRS Dataset to return single record to be used in Textbox properties

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008, filtering

I'm a total newbie when it comes to SSRS, so please excuse any use of wrong terminology. But I have been given a task to create a report that will have have a dataset that will contain records that will be used to set Textbox's font size and weight, underlined, justification, and text values. Something like this...

**Size**  **Bold**  **Underlined**  **Text**   **Identifier**
  10         Y            N          My Title    Title
  10         N            N          Some Def    Def1

Sorry about the misalignment in spacing. Not sure how to do a table here. But basically, I'm wondering if there is a way to write an expression that would allow me to get the record with the Identifier of "Title" and use the other fields in the textbox properties. Something like the where clause of Inline Linq. But I'm at a total lose and would greatly appreciate some help on this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this. In the TextBox properties, select the FontSize property and click on `<Expression..>`. Then in the expression box, pick the correct Dataset and field which will contain the font size.

Then repeat this process for the other attributes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: But how do I make it where the expression is filtered on the "Identifier = Title"

Comment: Setup the filter on the dataset: Dataset1 filter = "Identifier = Title1", Dataset2 filter = "Identifier = Def1"

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. So my next question is, is there a way to have a dataset query another dataset so I'm not having to hit the database 20 times.  Also, if I do have to hit the database 20 times, is there a way I can pass a value to a parameter from an expression? Something like "Fields!Font_Size.Value, Parameters!Identifier=Title".  And thank you for this help. I would love to get this report running by the end of day.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I may be thinking wrong about the statement on hitting the database. Since this is Sql Reporting, this would be done on the database. Therefore no requests are being made to the database. Is that correct?

Comment: I used your answer with the filter. Thank you so much for your help.